Correctly fit image size into existing PDF
I'm writing a simple application to convert images into single pages pdf files.
The application works fine (the full source code is available on github), but this method gives me some problem:
    private void CreateDoc(string srcFilename, string folder, PageSize pageSize)
    {
        string dstFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(srcFilename) + ".pdf");

        using PdfWriter writer = new(dstFilename);
        using PdfDocument pdfDocument = new(writer);


        iText.IO.Image.ImageData imageData = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(srcFilename);

        iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new(imageData);

        iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle? rectangle = null;

        if (pageSize == PageSize.ImageSize)
        {
            rectangle = new(0, 0, (int)image.GetImageWidth(), (int)image.GetImageHeight());
        }
        else
        {
            rectangle = pageSize.PdfSize();
            if (rectangle != null)
                image.ScaleToFit(
                    rectangle.GetWidth(),
                    rectangle.GetHeight());
            else throw new Exception("Page size not supported!");
        }

        if (rectangle == null)
            throw new Exception("Page not created!");

        iText.Layout.Document document = new(pdfDocument, new iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize(rectangle));

        float offX = (rectangle.GetWidth() - image.GetImageScaledWidth()) / 2;
        float offY = (rectangle.GetHeight() - image.GetImageScaledHeight()) / 2;

        image.SetFixedPosition(offX, offY);

        document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        document.Add(image);
    }

The method creates a pdf document within folder with just one page containing one image (srcFilename), the third parameter is the size of the page where the image will be placed (the image will be scaled to fit the page), pageSize can be one of the typical paper sheet sizes or ImageSize.
The application can also scan a pdf file to collect page sizes.
If I specify a proper paper sheet size (like A4, Legal ..) the pdf page created matches the size of the paper but since the source image almost never match a sheet size white borders occours. If I wish to avoid such borders I need to set pageSize = ImageSize ... in this case the page is created without white borders but it is much larger than a proper page size (2x, 3x).
How can I compute/apply a scaling factor to minimize the size differences?
